# change an integer to base 2 with arrays as output in C

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
 int main(void){
    
 

    int Num;
    int i;
    int N;
    int x = 0;
    int a[x];
    scanf("%d", &Num);
    
    N = Num;
    
    
    for(i = 0; i < Num; i++)
    {if (Num%2 == 0)
      {a[i] = 0;}
      else
      {a[i] = 1;}
      Num = Num/2;
    }printf("%d in base 2 is %d", N, a[x]);

        return 0;
        }
```

program should convert an integer Num to base 2 eg 17 to 10001.
ideally using an array as the output
the remainder of the division of Num by 2 should be the last number in the output
then number is divided by 2 and the process repeats with the second output becoming the 2nd last output of the array
Sorry if this question is worded badly
Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: `int x = 0; int a[x];` ==> `int a[64]; /* good for 64 bits computers*/`

Comment: pmg I just tried that and the output for 19 which should be 10011 is now -2 if you know how to fix that it would be appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You only ever set `a[i]` to `0` or `1`... so if you're getting `-2` you're not printing a valid element of the array `a` (maybe even you're *out of bounds*).

Comment: Im printing a[i] how do I make that valid, I dont have much knowledge on arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void){
    int Num;
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &Num);
    int x = floor(log2(Num)) +1;
    int a[x];
    N = Num;

    for(size_t i=0;i<x;i++){
        if(Num%2 == 0){
            a[i]=0;
        }else{
            a[i]=1;
        }
    Num /= 2;
    }

   printf("%d in base 2 is ",N);
   for(int i=x-1; i>=0;i--){
      printf("%d",a[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

---

I think the above code works fine for what you need (although it's not the best way to code this program).

In line 7 of your code, you defined `x` as `0`; so, in line 8, the length of your array is `0` – and that's not what we need.

At the end, when you want to output the result, you only output the *x<sup>th</sup>* element of your array. Instead, we want to output every element that we stored. (I used `i--` because, if I did not, the binary of `Num` would be reversed.)